# How can I execute code when an object is created through the chatter feed?

Tags: apex, trigger, chatter, feeditem

When a record is created from the chatter feed, it creates a FeedItem, but this FeedItem won't execute the trigger.

Is there a setting to allow the trigger to execute?

If not, is there another way to execute code when this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar issue when a live chat transcript is created as a FeedItem on the case object. I didn't find any work arounds for this problem. So I moved my code from FeedItem trigger to Case object Trigger.

Comment: So, short answer, you can't run the trigger for the FeedItem.